# How to host grafana on azure cloud?

Tags: reactjs, azure, web-applications, hosting, grafana

i have followed the https://grafana.com/docs/project/building_from_source/ and set up grafana in my local physical machine. Now am running it using `yarn start` and also starting grafana-server and it is working perfectly fine. Now i want to move it to Azure.

I am completely new to hosting procedures hence i would need some step by step instruction to host the created grafana over there in Azure

Answer (score 0):

There is no managed service for graphana, you need to install it on a VM using an existing image or manually, you can find the image from the [`market place`](https://azuremarketplace.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/apps/grafana-labs.grafana_oss)

Comment: in that case what would be the URL endpoint for my grafana? i would be accessing using similar way like localhost :3000  there.

how can i access from remote machines?

Answer (score 0):

here is a more detailed step, and it helps me out

https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/azure-monitor/platform/grafana-plugin.md

Using the IP address of your server, open the Login page at HTTP://:3000 or the :3000 in your browser. While 3000 is the default port, note you might have selected a different port during setup. You should see a login page for the Grafana server you built.